# Converting an ng-repeat into an infinite scroll in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http

Currently in Angular I am making an http request to a JSON news feed. I'm initiating the http request on load with data-ng-init="init()". However I would like the show just one article and have an infinite scroll. In other words, I would like the other articles to load, once a user gets to the bottom of each article.

This is my current index.html

```
<section ng-app="sports" ng-controller="main" data-ng-init="init()">
    <div ng-repeat="article in articles | limitTo:2">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- <h3>{{ article.created }}</h3> -->
            <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
            <img class="images afkl-lazy-image" src="{{ article.thumbnail }}">      
            <p ng-bind-html=" article.body | html "></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is my angularApp.js:

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.init = function(){
        $http.get("/data")
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.articles = [];
            $.each(response.node,function(index,item){
                $scope.articles.push(item);
            })
            $scope.articles.reverse();
        });
    }}
);
```

I will be around to answer any questions. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: How is this jQuery related?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a scroll listener to the page, catch the event and load more data one "page" at a time:

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;

$scope.loadPage = function(pageNum){

   $http.get("/data?page=" + pageNum)
      .success(function(response) {
          $scope.currentPage = pageNum;
          $.each(response.node,function(index,item){
              $scope.articles.push(item);
          })

      });
   }}
};

window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >=     document.body.offsetHeight) {
       $scope.loadPage($scope.currentPage + 1);

    }
};
```

You should really inject $window service and use it:

```
...controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $window) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
       ///check to see if you're at the bottom and call method to load data as above
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that you are just adding to the current array so the ng-repeat will automatically take care of adding it to the page.

Comment: This is actually really great but I dont understand: $http.get("/data?page=" + pageNum). All my data is located at "/data", what would a query string do?

Comment: If you want to load individual items in your list one at a time, your backend will need to know how to send only one at a time. Normally you would do a "page" at a time, which could be 5 items for example, but you could control that on your back end. If you just want to send it all to the front end in one shot, but only show a little at a time, you could store all of the items in an array (called 'allItems' for example), and in the scroll handler just copy one item at a time into a "displayedItems" array. Then use that in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think handling it on the front end would be my best bet.